# Wondering why my rear triangle crashes around everytime I use the rear triangle

Tags: noise, shocks

My Kona Stinky Deluxe’s rear triangle always makes a lot of noise whenever it is put to work (going over a pothole, etc.). Whenever I lift the back and drop it the rear of the bike doesn’t bounce, just make a lot of noise and vibrates a little. I was wondering if it has anything to do with the rear shock not compressing? Or is there some other problems?

Comment: Did you service the shocks at all? What is their mileage? The service is not simple and if they are damaged too much, they may have to be replaced. Your bushings may also be worn. Please try to show some pictures or a video.

Comment: Can you rule out the chain and rear derailleur? Same noise and vibrations even on the biggest sprockets?

Comment: How do I fix the preload adjuster? Do I need to take it apart? Because I don’t think I have the necessary tools to do so.

Answer (score 3):

There are several potential sources of noise and vibration in a full suspension bike's rear triangle.  Bushing wear in the shock linkages is a big one. My 2002 Stumpjumper had a noise that really bugged me for a time.  I even used generous torque on all the linkages before finally realizing after doing some reading that the DU bushings in the eyelets were worn and that created space for just a little movement (around 1mm or less) which led to a clunk that could be heard and felt.  New DU bushings solved that issue.

The Kona Stinky deluxe uses a coil spring.  Sometimes the preload adjuster, which imparts a baseline force on the spring at rest, is too loose or otherwise messed up which can lead to a bit of motion in the uncompressed spring.   Loose or overly worn linkage bolts, bushings or bearings can be a source of the noises you hear. Chain slap is another possibilty, which is when the top run of chain contacts the right chain stay.  This sound is rather distinctive compared to other sounds that we try to chase down.

Other noise sources outside the rear triangle include loose spokes, loose brake rotor, weak brake pad spring that allows the pads to move slightly and contact inside areas of the caliper.  Brake and derailleur cables can slap on the frame too if they're not insulated.  This includes the outer cable as well.  Here's a picture of a Kona Stinky where I've marked likely sources of noise from the rear triangle. I would start from the shock and move out from there in a search for noise sources.

[image: Kona Stinky rear triangle noise sources]